# What is the value of each rarity of cards in coins?

Tags: clash-royale

My question is, What is the approximate value of each rarity of cards in coins? I have seen in an earlier video (the video is for the best way to spend gems. It is now outdated), that commons are worth 2 coins, rares are worth 20, epics are worth 500. Is this still true?

Comment: why the downvote? If there is anything that I should improve please tell me.

Comment: Do you have a link to this video?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are down voted because your question can easily be tested by yourself or found online.
Anyway, [here](http://clashroyale.wikia.com/wiki/Gold) are the values in gold compared to their rarity

- Common : 5
- Rare : 50
- Epic : 500
- Legendary : 20000

Also you talk about a video in the question without providing a link [this guide](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) for the next questions

Comment: I actually thought that the video was not related to the topic, since it was about the best ways to spend gems. Anyway thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly:

- Commons: 2
- Rares: 20
- Epics: 1000
- Legendaries: 40,000

However, there are many distorting factors. For example, each card you buy from the shop (in a row )costs more than the previous one. Or that because some are more likely to get into chests, you need to buy them less often. Or that it takes different amounts of each to upgrade. Or that you get different amounts of gold for donating them. Etc, etc.

Comment: Those are the cards' shop value, not the actual one. See the other answers for the actual values.